# R code for returning value when matched the values

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and was wondering if I could get some help on a problem I am stuck on. 
I have two dataframes: First data frame has three columns: ID, sire.ID, and Dam.ID

```
df1
  ID Sire.ID Dam.ID
1  A       D      G
2  B       E      H
3  C       F      I
```

The second dataframe has the same three columns plus genotyping calls for 17 markers in 17 columns.

```
Part of df2:
ID Sire.ID Dam.ID marker1 marker2 marker3 marker4 marker5 marker6 marker7 marker8 marker9
1  D       j      K      12      21      11      11      12      22      11      22      11
2  G       l      m      12      21      11      11      12      22      11      22      11
3  H       n      o      12      21      11      11      12      22      11      22      11
```

Here is what I need to be done in R: If sire.ID in the first dataframe exists in the ID column in the second dataframe, then return the ID and its calls from the second dataframe in first dataframe for the relevant offspring, and same for Dam.ID. Simply, for each ID in the first dataframe I want to get the calls for its sire and dam in front of the ID and in two rows.

```
Expected output: ID Sire.ID Dam.ID ID..4 Sire.ID..5 Dam.ID..6 marker1 marker2 marker3 marker4 marker5 marker6 marker7 1  A       D      G    D          j         K      12      21      11      11      12      22 11 2  A       D      G     G          l         m      12      21      11      11      12      22      11 3  B       E      H     H          n         o      12      21      11      11      12      22      11   marker8 marker9 1      22      11 2      22      11 3      22      11
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear about what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you need to INNER JOIN the two data frames. Use the `sqldf` package, then run

```
sires <- sqldf('SELECT df1.ID, df2.marker1, df2.marker2, ... df2.marker17
FROM df1 INNER JOIN df2 ON  df1."sire.ID" = df2."sire.ID"')
Dams <- sqldf('SELECT df1.ID, df2.marker1, df2.marker2, ... df2.marker17
FROM df1 INNER JOIN df2 ON  df1."Dam.ID" = df2."Dam.ID"')
```

That creates two data frames, one with the sires data and one with the Dams data. (Note that you only need `ID` from the first data frame, and only the markers from the second data frame. Make sure to fill in the correct column names in each of the SQL calls. Also, take careful note of the single-quotes around the entire `sqldf` code, and then the double-quotes around the specific column names that have periods in them.)

Your next step is going to be to do an `rbind()` to combine the two data frame:

```
newdata <- rbind(sires, Dams)
```

That will create a final data frame that will combine the data from the sires and the Dams, recording the ID number and the marker numbers. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Note that this could be done entirely in sql: `sqldf("select ... union select ...")`.  The column names should be the same.

Comment: or if there are duplicates that you don't want eliminated use `union all`.